# jQuery select one item when related button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to show the code sample first:

```
<div class="text-muted"> Question 1</div>
<li class="question-statement">First Question</li>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-1"><span> Option A</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-1"><span> Option B</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-1"><span> Option C</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-1"><span> Option D</span>
</div>
<button type="button" class="checkAnswer">Check Answer</button>


<div class="text-muted"> Question 2</div>
<li class="question-statement">Second Question</li>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="a" name="q-2"><span> Option A</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="b" name="q-2"><span> Option B</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="c" name="q-2"><span> Option C</span>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="d" name="q-2"><span> Option D</span>
</div>
<button type="button" class="checkAnswer">Check Answer</button>
```

I send an ajax request to get all the questions and answers. Here is the response from the server when I receive the response:

```
[{
    "id": 2243,
    "question": "Question 1",
    "a": "Option A",
    "b": "Option B",
    "c": "Option C",
    "d": "Option D",
    "answer": "Option B",
},
{
    "id": 2244,
    "question": "Question 2",
    "a": "Option A",
    "b": "Option B",
    "c": "Option C",
    "d": "Option D",
    "answer": "Option C",
}]
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<script>
     $('.checkAnswer').click(function () {
     console.log($(this))
   })
</script>
```

Actually I am trying to access the input fields of the selected question and add some css.

Here are two multiple choice questions with four options. One option is correct. I want to click on each button to see the correct answer individually. I can not figure out how to do it. Can anyone help? I want to do it with jQuery.

Comment: can provide your jQuery code ?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Which option is correct? Nothing seems obvious in the HTML, so i'm assuming it's stored in your JavaScript somewhere. So as @Pain said, could you provide your JavaScript code?

Comment: @Pain I have updated the question, do you have some clue now?

Comment: your html structure is not good create better html structure for example make div each question so you can access seperately to question what you want

Comment: How are you cross referencing the answers from the ajax request? 

Can you provide the JS for the ajax request that fetches the questions/answers? 

Are the questions individually hard coded into the html or is the html dynamically created after the ajax fetch?

Comment: The questions are dynamically fetched from the database. @McWayWeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let questionArr = [
  {
      "id": 2243,
      "question": "Question 1",
      "a": "Option A",
      "b": "Option B",
      "c": "Option C",
      "d": "Option D",
      "answer": "Option B",
  },
  {
      "id": 2244,
      "question": "Question 2",
      "a": "Option A",
      "b": "Option B",
      "c": "Option C",
      "d": "Option D",
      "answer": "Option C",
  }
];

questionArr.forEach((question) => {
  let html = `
    <div class="question">
      <div class="text-muted">${question.question}</div>
      <li class="question-statement">${question.question}</li>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="${question.a}" name="q-${question.id}"><span> ${question.a}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="${question.b}" name="q-${question.id}"><span> ${question.b}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="${question.c}" name="q-${question.id}"><span> ${question.c}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" value="${question.d}" name="q-${question.id}"><span> ${question.d}</span>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="checkAnswer" data-answer="${question.answer}">Check Answer</button>
    </div>
  `;
  $('#questions').append(html);
});

$(() => {
    $('.checkAnswer').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().find('.form-check-input:checked').val() == $(this).data('answer')) {
      console.log('correct answer');
    } else {
      console.log('incorrect answer');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="questions"></div>
```

You will need to replace the hard coded array data in **questionArr** with the results from the ajax fetch.

Also this is not a very secure approach in the sense that you have exposed the answers to all the questions on the client side, which may or may not be an issue for your app.

But if security is a concern, I would make individual ajax requests to retrieve each answer during the **$('.checkAnswer').click()** event and compare the answer to the from the new ajax response.